# How to have access to logcat without android device monitor?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Now that android device monitor has been deprecated, how to have access to the logcat of an Android device? Of course we can do `adb logcat` but it's not convenient at all to read/filter the logcat like this. is there any standalone tool available to replace android device monitor? I would like to avoid to use android studio just for that

Comment: I use logcat from cli quite a lot and it seems convenient to me. Especially if you specify the tag like so `adb logcat -s 'tag'`. Also there are many standalone tools that should fit your needs, just google "adb logcat tools"

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic.  You can ask such questions on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Please read their help center to learn about their rules.